# How to install "pthreads" on OSX, PHP 5.5.30

Tags: php, macos

I couldn't find any step-by-step guide how to install this thing on OSX. And I don't want to recompile PHP, if that's possible.

Is there simply a package that I can install from somewhere that will just enable pthreads? I tried with:

```
pecl install pthreads

pecl/pthreads requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0RC5), installed version is 5.5.30
No valid packages found
```

Answer (score 5):

Update php to version >= 7.0.0RC5 or install another version of pthreads

```
pecl install pthreads-2.0.10
```

Also pthreads will require that php is configurated with flag `--enable-maintainer-zts`. It is set on php compilation.

```
./configure ... --enable-maintainer-zts ...
make
make install
```